# IDE support for TypeScript inside <script> tags in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any support for getting live IDE support for TypeScript inside script tags?

For example, if I have

```html
<script type="text/typescript">
  function foo<T extends Function>(f: T) { /*...*/ }
</script>
```

Comment: Even support for `JSDoc` would be a win. I'm surprised this isn't supported :-( Were you able to find anything?

Comment: It seems plain JS with JSDoc inside script tags is working lately. I just tried it in VS Code. For example, try making an HTML file like the following in VS Code: https://plnkr.co/edit/i5JU4fsuY4C6cq6I. Not sure if we can get `tsc` to type check it though.

Comment: Oh, I missed adding `@ts-check`. Now I need to figure out how to pull in a `d.ts` type definitions. I'm doing this `/** @type {import("../@types/globals").CustomGlobal} */` but it gives me an error that I need `Cannot find module '../@types/globals'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?`. I'll have to create an example and ask a question here on SO about it. Unless you know :-). Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Jon49 Let's figure it out. If you ask the question, paste the link here. :)

Comment: Thanks for being willing to take a look at it. Here is the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/63965474/632495 . I won't have time to look at any answers until Sunday morning though.

Comment: I wish this would be a thing!